# Block linking in Enumerable's each, allowed?

Tags: ruby, each, enumerable

In many cases over internet i seen examples of `each` method for Enumerable as:

```rb
def each(&block)
  @items.each do |item|
    block.call(item)
  end
end
```

Why people not using this one:

```rb
def each(&block)
  @items.each(&block)
end
```

Is there any differences?

Comment: I am not a 100% sure so I won't create an answer, but AFAIK there is no practical difference (other than first being probably slower, and definitely more verbose). Why people use it? well, probably because it's as easy as it gets while the second requires some understanding about how to pass around blocks/Procs.

Comment: @tokland: That's not entirely correct, the first would have to return an enumerator if no block is given to be equivalent to the second.

Comment: @Niklas, oh, you're right, now Ruby returns an enumerator when no  block is passed to each. Yet another reason to use the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I think the following version is even more commonly seen:

```
def each
  @items.each { |i| yield i }
end
```

This is equivalent to your first code sample. There is however a subtle difference between this and your second version:

```
class Test
  def initialize(items)
    @items = items
  end

  def each1
    @items.each { |i| yield i }
  end

  def each2(&block)
    @items.each(&block)
  end
end
```

Observe:

```
irb(main):053:0> Test.new([1,2,3]).each2
=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each>
irb(main):054:0> Test.new([1,2,3]).each1
LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)
    from (irb):43:in `block in each1'
    from (irb):43:in `each'
    from (irb):43:in `each1'
    from (irb):54
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

The version that delegates the block to the underlying iterable actually returns an enumerator if no block is given, which is very nice. It allows us to write stuff like this:

```
irb(main):055:0> Test.new([1,2,3]).each2.map { |x| x + 1 }
=> [2, 3, 4]
```

To achieve the same with our explicit version, we'd have to adapt it like this:

```
def each1
  return enum_for(:each1) unless block_given?
  @items.each { |i| yield i }
end
```

Which is even more verbose. Bottomline: Delegate the block to an underlying enumerable whenever possible, to save yourself from code duplication and from subtle gotchas like these.

By the way, now that you realize the two-folded nature of your `each` method, it would make sense to name it differently. For example, you could follow the example of methods like `String#chars` or `IO#lines` and call your method `items`:

```
def items(&block)
  @items.each(&block)
end
```

Comment: Thank you, your 3rd code example showed differences to me :) Looks like, i was right :)